# Control devices connected to raspberry pi from a webpage

Tags: raspberry-pi3, iot

I want to control my devices connected to Raspberry pi 3B+ from a webpage. Web page is a real website thus can be accesed from anywhere. How can I do this?

Answer (score 0):

There are a lot of ways to control devices. I use a raspberry to turn on and off a computer, from a web interface. I've connected a relay on the GPIO pins and I rewired the power button from the mainboard of the computer, to run through the relay.

The web interface runs using php. So, just a basic example of a script, running in php that makes the relay do a click looks like this:

```
shell_exec('/usr/local/bin/gpio -g mode 17 out');
shell_exec('/usr/local/bin/gpio -g write 17 1');
usleep(500000);
shell_exec('/usr/local/bin/gpio -g write 17 0');
```

The script sets pin 17 for output, then turns on the voltage on the pin, waits half a second then turns off the voltage. The relay is connected to ground and pin 17 on the GPIO, of course.

Keep in mind that this is a very basic example of using GPIO from php, without any libraries.

Comment: Whether this **web inerface** is local on raspberry pi or not

Comment: In my case, the web interface is hosted on the raspberry pi. My router forwards port 443 to the pi, so the web interface is public and accessible from anywhere, since I have a domain pointing to the router.

Comment: if web interface is not local to pi then what i have to do

Answer (score 0):

One simple way to do this is as follows:

1) deploy an MQTT broker on the public cloud or use a free public broker such as iot.eclipse.org if data security isn't a concern
2) Implement a javascript MQTT client on the website that can subscribe to and publish to MQTT topics on the broker
3) Implement another client on the raspberry pi in a language of your choice and link that to your devices

If you want your data to be encrypted, you can also set up transport layer security using OpenSSL certificates